# SQL constraint to enforce x number of instances for a given combination of columns

Tags: sql, unique-constraint

Let's say I have a SQL table called `PersonClub` with the following columns: `person_id`, `club_id`, `year`

I'd like to apply the following constraint: "A person can belong to only 3 different clubs in a given year."

Is there any way to enforce this at the database level? Or is this not possible?

Comment: Feels more like a job for a trigger but please say what db you use

Comment: @CaiusJard PostgreSQL